# GoogleApiClient doesn't connect

Tags: android, google-api-client

I pressed menu key after I choosed one account to sign in with google api client, then i click this app to front ,the googleapiclient doesn't connect anymore. of course i called connect() method in fragment's onstart() and disconnect() in onStop().
  if account signed in successfully, now I don't need to choose account when sign in, I pressed menu key and click it back, the app will sign in successfully!

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestIdToken(Settings.VAL_GOOGLE_REQ_ID_TOKEN).requestEmail().build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

Comment: Welcome - please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Are you Using Google Api Client in Fragment Or activity 
If you want to use enableAutoManage then you must make your activity extend FragmentActivity. The callbacks it makes are required for the automatic management of the GoogleApiClient to work. So the easiest solution is to add extends FragmentActivity to your activity. Then your cast would not fail and cause the app to crash at runtime.

The alternate solution is to manage the api client yourself. You would remove the enableAutoManage line from the builder, and make sure you connect/disconnect from the client yourself. The most common place to do this is onStart()/onStop(). Something like...

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this).build();
```

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {

```
super.onStart();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

```
super.onStop();
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
```

}